# Cross-compatibility for filenames on Mac OSX/Windows?

Tags: mac, filenames

If I was to share images and wanted to make them work on both Mac OS X/Catalina and Windows, would this practise be good:

```
My_Holiday_Italy_August_2014_0001.jpg
My Holiday Italy August 2014 0001.jpg
My-Holiday-Italy-August-2014-0001.jpg
```

Obviously I can't use `/` or `\` even if Mac OSX reads them.

I've got a file renaming utility for MacOS Catalina but before renaming want to ensure that the names are cross-compatible.

With regards to filenames is 0001 better than 1, 01, 001 for a sequence of filenames, and as for underscores does that work?

I would welcome any advice on how to improve my filename cross-compatibility practices.

Answer (score 0):

From a technically point of view, either of your suggestions work and don't make any difference. Which to prefer is almost subjective, I for example mostly prefer underscores over dashes. OTOH, with the case you have in your words, I would prefer spaces, though. Simply because things look more like natural language and sentences to me this way.

But here's the problem: While spaces don't make a difference technically and are fine to be used in theory, some people avoid them as they might make trouble when used in combination with e.g. command line apps. Reason is that spaces are used to distinguish different arguments to those apps from each other and if paths are not properly quoted, things might simply fail. Look at the following example:

```
some_app arg_1 arg_2  My Holiday Italy August 2014 0001.jpg
some_app arg_1 arg_2  My_Holiday_Italy_August_2014_0001.jpg
some_app arg_1 arg_2 "My Holiday Italy August 2014 0001.jpg"
```

I regularly consider software failing to work with paths with spaces simply being buggy. You need to decide on your own if you want to risk not being able to use some software only because of file naming and sometimes it's not even the software you use directly which is buggy, but something different that is used by that software etc. For similar reason some people often don't use non-ASCII characters.

Regarding your suffix, you should prefer 0-aligned ones like `0001` and `0123` instead of `1` and `123`, like you did already. While it doesn't make any technical difference again, it makes sorting and stuff easier for most tools. It might even make filtering your names for further mass renaming easier at some point.

Besides that, don't overthink this too much. You will change your mind at some point for some reason anyway and prefer a different naming scheme, like splitting same named files into same named directories and stuff like that. No one prevents you from using additional directories, which is essentially what using `\` or `/` means in the end.